# Session is transparent from user

Tags: session, session-state

Can anyone tell me what is the meaning of "Session is transparent from user.". I want to know that how Session transparent from user.

Comment: What language/technology is this? A quick Google search on the phrase "Session is transparent from user" yields 0 results.

Comment: Of-course in ASP.NET.I think Session use only in ASP.NET State management.

Answer (score 0):

It means that whatever are the internal details(how the session was built) is hidden from the user but the user can see the session going on.

Here is an example to help you out,

> You know how to drive a car but you don't need to know how to built a
>   car to drive it, so the implementation of the car is transparent from
>   you but you still can drive the car without knowing how it is built.